# How can I access call history that no longer shows up on my phone?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, call

I understand that the call log on the iPhone only holds 100 calls.I missed a call a few weeks ago and I know the approximate date and time I received it. Scrolling through the call log on the iPhone I don't see the call any longer, I also don't see it in the log from AT&T as I didn't pick up the call.

Is there a call history on iCloud (or somewhere else) which I could use to figure out where the missed call was coming from?

Comment: Are you sure of the approximate date? Your service provider should be able to give you a log of incoming calls, regardless whether you picked them up.

Comment: @christian Check the edit history, I removed the part where the OP called AT&T support exactly for this. Apparently they can‘t.